# Office Excel add-in not found

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, office-store

I have an Excel add-in that was certified and published about two weeks ago, but I can't find it from Excel, google search or any other methods.

Is there still something, i need to do for add-in to appear?

I also need to get the URL to add-in page, so that I can insert it to my website. Is it possible?

Comment: What's your Add-in name? Can you find it at https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?product=office%3Bexcel&page=1

Comment: "Yhteisötieto" in finnish and "Finnish Community Info" in english.
No, I can't find it from appsource.microsoft.com.

Comment: How do you know if the publish was success?